# Reading zip archive files for content

Tags: powershell, search, zip, tortoisesvn, pscx

I created the following code, but it is not actually reading any of the .zip or .prd files as expected, but the other parts are working. Might you help me figure out why it is not actually reading the zip files in the ForEach loop?

```
#Set variables for subversion paths
$ScriptPath = (Split-Path $myinvocation.MyCommand.path -Parent)
#$Package = $ScriptPath

#Create folder for temporary copy of SVN directory
New-Item C:\MyTemp-type directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
New-Item C:\Results -type directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
Test-Path $profile
New-item –type file –force $profile

#Set variables for subversion paths
$CurrentSVNPath = "http://MySVNPath" 
$TempSVNPath = "C:\MyTemp"
$ResultsFilePath = "C:\Results"

#Download a local copy of the SVN Repository
 # Wait for command to finish before moving forward
#$SVNDownloadJob = Start-Job {SVN Checkout $CurrentSVNPath $TempSVNPath}
$SVNDownloadJob = Start-Job {TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\SVN_Repo" /closeonend:1 | Out-Null} 
Wait-Job $SVNDownloadJob
Receive-Job $SVNDownloadJob

#Find pattern to search for within all files from where this script is run
#If you do not want to look for the standard pattern uncomment/comment the $Pattern variables
    #$Pattern = Read-Host 'What pattern are you looing for?'
    $Pattern = "Simulate=`"true`""
    $SearchPattern = “Simulate=`”true`””
    $PackageList = Get-ChildItem –Path $ScriptPath –Recurse –filter “*.zip, *.prd”

#Start searching all folders where this script exists for 'Simulate=true'
$k =foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Path $ScriptPath -Recurse | Select-String -pattern $Pattern | Select-Object -Unique path) {$file.path}
$k > "$($ResultsFilePath)\SimulateEqualsTrueZipFiles.txt"

Foreach ( $Package in $PackageList) {
Read-Archive -$_.Path -Format Zip | `
   Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*.zip" } | `
  Expand-Archive -PassThru | select-string $SearchPattern | Select-Object -Unique path {$file.path}
  $k > "$($ResultsFilePath)\SimulateEqualsTrueZipFiles.txt"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the contents of Zip Folder by using below cmdlets

```
$ZipFile="Path"
$AllFile=Get-ChildItem $ZipFile -Recurse -Filter '*.zip'
$ObjArray = @() 
foreach ($item in $AllFile){
   $FullName=$item.FullName
    $RawFiles = [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($FullName).Entries            
    $FullPathName=$FullName+"\"+"$RawFile"
foreach($RawFile in $RawFiles) { 

  $object = New-Object -TypeName PSObject            
  $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FileName -Value $RawFile.Name   
  $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FullPath -Value $FullPathName            
  $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CompressedLengthInKB -Value ($RawFile.CompressedLength/1KB).Tostring("00")            
  $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UnCompressedLengthInKB -Value ($RawFile.Length/1KB).Tostring("00")            
  $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FileExtn -Value ([System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($RawFile.FullName))            
  $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ZipFileName -Value $zipfile            
  $ObjArray += $Object            
 }

 }
```

Make sure dot net 4.5 is installed before running the above cmdlets.

Comment: Just to verify with you. Is the "Zip Folder Path":  C:\MyTemp or C:\MyTemp\foo.zip or C:\MyTemp\*.zip?  I'm hoping it's as simple as C:\MyTemp as I have hundreds of zip files to search.

Comment: @Underdog Edited the script. Now you can supply c:\mytemp in the 'path'. It will fetch you the details of all zip folders inside c:\mytemp

Comment: I wish I could report back that your sample works, but it is not outputting a file with a list of the ziparchive names where "Simulate=`"true`"".  I've made a few changes and it still doing what I have above.

Comment: I suggest you to out file $Object inside the loop to get the out file of the data ($object | out-file "Path" -append)

Comment: Okay, it's now reading into the zip files, but how to I get it to list the name of the file with the full path? (example: C:\MyTemp\xyz.zip\myText.txt)

Comment: I edited the script. Now 'fullpath' parameter will give you the name of the file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127059/discussion-between-venkatakrishnan-and-underdog).

Comment: It's almost there and I'll post the changes I've made to get it to work. Thank you very much for helping me a long this code.  Any idea why it's only writing back "C:\MyTem\xy......"?

Comment: Instead of $object, you can outfile like                echo " $object.name, $object.fullname " | out-file 'filepath' -append

Comment: Now it's reading the zip files and reporting back the full path. What would I add to have a blank space between file names.  Do you think if I add the same code with in this code to look for inside other zip archives it would work?  (example: C:\MyTemp\xyz.zip\zyx.zip\myText.zip)

Comment: I now having it reading every file within a zip file and a second zip file within a zip file. However, I am getting the name of every file, not just the ones where my code is looking for ($Pattern = "Simulate=`"true`""). I've added this code to the code but I'm sure it's not working. `$Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SimulateTrue -Value $1K`

Comment: An zip file inside zip wont be visible using the above script.Its not possible to get the data in 'C:\MyTemp\xyz.zip\zyx.zip\myText.zip) ' format. Because .zip extension wont allow us to further dig into it.

Comment: I think I have the code working to look inside a C:\MyTemp\xyz.zip\zyx.zip\myText.txt but the code seems to only be listing the file names not the content inside the file.  Do you think that I should extract everything first than search it and delete?  Possibly using a function inside the second foreach loop [Extract-Zip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28448202/i-want-to-extract-all-zip-files-in-a-given-directory-in-temp-using-powershell.)

Comment: Any chance you might have something I can play with that will unzip multiple zip files into a temporary directory, that I can than unzip the multiple zip files within that temporary directory and scan.  I'm trying different things right now but I just don't quite have the code working well enough.