# Unzip a file on multiple remote servers via Powershell

Tags: powershell, unzip

I'm currently writing a simple PowerShell script.
Basically, it should get the list of servers from a notepad and start to unzip the .zip file on each server and extract it to the new folder.

However, the script is not extracting all files under the zip file.
It would only extract one file from it and I'm not sure why the foreach loop not working properly.

Please shed some light on this issue. Thanks.

```
$servers = Get-Content "C:\tmp\script\new_unzip\servers.txt"
$Date = ((Get-Date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss'))
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    $shell = new-object -com shell.application
    $target_path = "\\$server\c$\Temp\FFPLUS_Temp"
    $location = $shell.namespace($target_path)
    $ZipFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $target_path -Filter *.zip
    $ZipFiles | Unblock-File

    foreach ($ZipFile in $ZipFiles) {
        $ZipFile.fullname | out-default
        $NewLocation = "\\$server\c$\Temp\FFPLUS_Temp\$Date"
        New-Item $NewLocation -type Directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        Move-Item $ZipFile.fullname $NewLocation -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $NewZipFile = Get-ChildItem $NewLocation *.zip
        $NewLocation = $shell.namespace($NewLocation)
        $ZipFolder = $shell.namespace($NewZipFile.fullname)
        $NewLocation.copyhere($ZipFolder.items())
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to extract all .zip files in a given directory in temp using powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28448202/i-want-to-extract-all-zip-files-in-a-given-directory-in-temp-using-powershell)

Comment: I'm trying to extract the file on multiple remote servers but it only unzip one file out of 3 files. I didn't receive any error but somehow it doesn't properly.

Comment: I'm using the ExtractToDirectory method which is included in .NET Framework 4.5 as an alternative way.

Comment: @MuthukumaranThavarajoo So am I and it has the same issue.  It works fine locally but fails to copy all files when ran in an `Invoke-Command` to be ran on the server I'm trying to unzip on.

Comment: @Matt Arnold, I did with the alternative way & it works

Answer (score 0):

```
$servers = Get-Content "C:\tmp\script\updated\servers.txt"
$Date = ((Get-Date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy_HH-mm-ss'))

foreach ($server in $servers)
{

$zipFolder = "\\$server\c$\Temp\FFPLUS_Temp"

Add-Type -assembly System.IO.Compression.Filesystem

$zipFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $zipFolder -Filter *.zip

foreach($zip in $zipFiles)
    {
        $destPath = "\\$server\c$\Temp\FFPLUS_Temp\$Date"      

        New-Item -ItemType Directory $destPath  

        [io.compression.zipfile]::ExtractToDirectory([string]$zip.FullName, "$destPath")

        Move-Item $zip.fullname $destPath -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue        
    }           

}
```

Comment: this is the alternative way to unzip the same files on multiple servers