# Powershell unzip files into a specific folder

Tags: powershell

I am trying to unzip a set of folders that looks like this

```
a.zip
b.zip
c.zip
```

into a folder call "extracted" with their content extracted into the same respective names.

```
a folder
b folder
c folder
```

I am using the following code based off [I want to extract all .zip files in a given directory in temp using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28448202/i-want-to-extract-all-zip-files-in-a-given-directory-in-temp-using-powershell)

```
Get-ChildItem $foldername -Filter *.zip | Expand-Archive -DestinationPath $foldernameExtract -Force
```

It does the extraction into the extract folder but the items in each zip were done in "extract here" method instead of "extract to folders" in extract folder.

Was wondering if there is a way to tidy them up?

Comment: Define "messed up".

Comment: @Drew the style of items extracted was "extract here" instead of "extract to folder location"

Comment: Please don't extent your question with comment. Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code to the below.

```
Get-ChildItem $foldername -Filter *.zip | ForEach-Object {Expand-Archive $_.FullName "$foldernameExtract\$($_.Basename)" -Force}
```

You need to loop through each zip file and use its name along with the full path to save them into.